# Conditional Forwarding intermittent failures

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2022

We have 2 DCs, 1 on 2019 and one on 2022 (also a third on 2012..but soon to be demoted so not relevant)

-All have the SAME conditional forward to a 3rd party company domain (sanitized) -> "xx.service.contso.tv" as well as a conditional reverse lookup.

- DC1 (2019) resolves via nslookup fine...no issues; it seems to just work
- DC2 (2022) resolves seems to resolve everything fine EXCEPT "storage.service.contso.tv"

It appears to work for a bit...then goes non-existent domain. Sometimes it comes back on its own, and if I restart the DNS server service, or i flush dns and reregister it works for a bit too...but it will inevitably go down.

This other domain is not administered by me, but by the 3rd party company for Broadcast television playout.
Both are on Different subnets (2019 on old and 2022 on new) so there is that... but the 2019 is 1 hop further away than the 2022 (4 vs 5)
Both of these dcs are currently on the same VM server (moved back as i though it was the other vm server)

Did an nslookup d2 for first time it looks like when its in fail mode its trying to hit godaddy or some DNS host.
All root forwarders, helper, etc look the same... tried AD replication on and off, manually etc and its still happens. Tried reinstalling the DNS server feature and still same.

Since this other network is not mine, im a bit limited what i can do on the other end. and they are kind of helpful...but its the type of company where unless you can prove its there issue,they wont do anything. So if it is my server, i want to see where it rejects it and if its them.. I want to see there ip reject it.

Tried looking at wire shark too..but either its not there or im missing it.......

If it means anything this "storage" fqdn is actually a delegate record for an isilon smart connect too..so maybe its a smart connect issue on there end...but then it works fine on 2019 still so...
and all things are same (root forwarder, helpsers, etc)

I have also read about port exhaustion, edns settings etc...but im not fully aware of where to look for these in that regard (or if its even relevent as these are all for server 2012,2008, and 2012 from my reading)

Im pretty ready to burn the 2022 Domain controller and spark up A 2019 but my intent was to have a2 on 2022

Comment: one thing i JUST noticed... in vCenter...both had same type of adapter (vmnxnet3) but this particular server had "allow direct path enabled" while all other servers do not.....